# Constraining frequencies when building a list of lists of integers

Tags: python, list

I am trying to write a function which will return a list of lists of integers corresponding to pools that I will pool chemicals in. I want to keep the number of chemicals in each pool as uniform as possible. Each chemical is replicated some number of times across pools (in this example, 3 times across 9 pools). For the example below, I have 31 chemicals. Thus, each pool should have 10.333 drugs in it (or, more specifically, each pool should have floor(93/9) = 10 drugs with 93%9 = 3 pools having 11 drugs. My function for doing so is below. Currently, I'm trying to get the function to loop until there is one set of integers left (i.e. 3 pools with 9 chemicals) so that I can code the function to recognize which pools are allowed one more chemical and finalize the list of lists that tells me which pools to put each chemical in.

However, as written right now, the function will not always give my desired distribution of 11,11,11,10,10,10,9,9,9 for the frequencies of integers appearing in the list of lists. I've written the following to attempt to constrain the distribution: **1)** Randomly select, without replacement, a list of bits (pool numbers). If any of the bits in the selected list have frequency >= 10 in the output list and I already have 3 pools with frequency 11, discard this list of bits. **2)** If any of the bits in the selected list have frequency >= 9 in the output list, and there are 6 pools with frequency >= 10, discard this list of bits. **3)** If any of the bits in the selected list have frequency >= 11 in the output list, discard this list of bits. **It seems that this bit of code isn't working properly. I'm thinking it's either related to me improperly coding these three conditions. It appears that some lists of bits are being accidentally discarded while others are improperly added to the output list. Alternatively, there could be a scenario in which two pools go from 9 to 10 chemicals in the same step, resulting in 4 pools of 10 instead of 3 pools of 10. Am I thinking about this problem wrong? Is there an obvious place where my code isn't working?**

The function for generating normalized pools:
(overlapping_kbits returns a list of lists of bits of length *replicates* with each bit being an integer in the range [1,*pools*], filtered such that no two lists may have greater than *overlaps* between them.)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import re
import math
from collections import Counter

def normalized_pool(pools, replicates, overlaps, ligands):
    solvent_bits = [list(bits) for bits in itertools.combinations(range(pools),replicates)]
        
    print(len(solvent_bits))
    
    total_items = ligands*replicates
    norm_freq = math.floor(total_items/pools)
    num_extra = total_items%pools
    num_norm = pools-3
    normed_bits = []
    count_extra = 0
    count_norm = 0
    
    while len(normed_bits) < ligands-1 and len(solvent_bits)>0:
        rand = np.random.randint(0,len(solvent_bits))
        bits = solvent_bits.pop(rand) #Sample without replacement
        print(bits)
        bin_freqs = Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(normed_bits))
        print(bin_freqs)
        previous = len(normed_bits)
        
        #Constrain the frequency distribution
        count_extra = len([bin_freqs[bit] for bit in bin_freqs.keys() if bin_freqs[bit] >= norm_freq+1])
        count_norm = len([bin_freqs[bit] for bit in bin_freqs.keys() if bin_freqs[bit] >= norm_freq])
        if any(bin_freqs[bit] >= norm_freq for bit in bits) and count_extra == num_extra:
            print('rejected')
            continue #i.e. only allow num_extra number of bits to have a frequency higher than norm_freq
        elif any(bin_freqs[bit] >= norm_freq+1 for bit in bits):
            print('rejected')
            continue #i.e. never allow any bit to be greater than norm_freq+1
        elif (any(bin_freqs[bit] >= norm_freq-1 for bit in bits) and count_norm >= num_norm):
            if count_extra == num_extra:
                print('rejected')
                continue #only num_norm bins can have norm_freq
        
        normed_bits.append(bits)
    
    bin_freqs = Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(normed_bits))

    return normed_bits

test_bits = normalized_pool(9,3,2,31)
test_freqs = Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(test_bits))
print(test_freqs)
print(len(test_bits))
```

I can get anything from 11,11,11,10,10,10,9,9,9 (my desired output) to 11,11,11,10,10,10,10,10,7. For a minimal example, try:

```
test_bits = normalized_pool(7,3,2,10)
test_freqs = Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(test_bits))
print(test_freqs)
```

Which should return 5,5,4,4,3,3,3 as the elements of the test_freqs Counter.

**EDIT: Modified the function so it can run from being copied and pasted. Merged the function call into the larger block of code since it was being overlooked.**

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: Please note that your code does not run -- it defines a function and quits without executing.  Also, the code is not minimal: you should be able to reproduce the problem with fewer chemicals and pools, no?  We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the suspected values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.  Specifically point out where you get lost in this process: **that** is where Stack Overflow takes over.  :-)

Comment: @Prune I have modified the code block such that it will run upon a simple copy-paste. The function call was previously in the smaller of the two code blocks. There are now two function calls as two examples of arguments which produce the same phenomenon. I had removed print statements that I was using for basic diagnosis for readability. They have now been included. Where I am getting lost in this process is the if/elif/elif block where it appears that some lists of bits are not being properly discarded, perhaps due to incorrect formatting of the if blocks.

Comment: Great; when the specifics are done, I'll take a walk through it.

Comment: @Prune what do you mean by specifics? I don't think I'm leaving anything out.

Comment: You have several critical unresolved anaphors (references) in your discussion of the problem.  Most notably, "some lists ..." and "perhaps due to ...".  Since you have not yet produced the requested execution trace, we don't know which lists aren't discarded, and it seems that you haven't yet investigated whether you have correct formatting.  These are part of the basic diagnosis I mentioned earlier.

Comment: I have added print statements to trace through the execution of the function over the while loop where I believe the problem is. I misspoke before, the formatting is fine but the expressions used in the if/elif statements may be incorrect. Upon running the function, some lists pass the conditions to be included but these lists make the desired distribution impossible to achieve. In some cases, one bit's frequency lags behind the others and it becomes impossible to get a list of bits which satisfies the desired distribution (i.e. if bit 4 has frequency 7 instead of 9, we can't have [4,4,6])